# Airflow BashOperator Pass Arguments between Python Scripts

Tags: python, anaconda, airflow

In order to run Python scripts inside virtualenv when scheduled using Apache Airflow, the `BashOperator` is used.

For example,

```
task_a = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_a',
    bash_command='/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python /path/to/script_a.py'),
    dag=dag)

task_b = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_b',
    bash_command='/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python /path/to/script_b.py'),
    dag=dag)
```

In this case, how can we pass data between `task_a` and `task_b`, like how you could when using Xcom when the `PythonOperator` is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='task_a') }}` as an argument to your script in `task_b`. Remember only last line of the output of `BashOperator` is pushed to Xcom.

```
task_a = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_a',
    bash_command='/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python /path/to/script_a.py'),
    dag=dag)

task_b = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_b',
    bash_command="/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python /path/to/script_b.py {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='task_a') }}"),
    dag=dag)
```